# Adding URL redirect showing path http instead of https in redirect

Tags: 10

I have ssl enabled but Adding URL redirect showing path http instead of https in redirect. How we can changes http to https.

[image]

Comment: Only the part you enter is stored. The absolute path before the input field is to show that you should enter the relative path starting here, but it doesn't reflect the value stored in the database. Even if it has no meaning in this context, if you want to debug this, please share the full URL you have in the browser address bar while visiting this form. Do you have a direct connection between browser and web server?

Comment: A classic reason this could happen is because there is a reverse proxy or load balancer that Drupal isn’t configured properly to use. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/getting-started/installing-drupal/using-a-load-balancer-or-reverse-proxy

Answer (score 1):

The prefix displayed in front of "Path" field is automatically generated according the current HTTP request with this code :

```
\Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost()
```

If you try to access this page with "https" you will see "https" inside the field prefix : https://example.com/admin/config/search/redirect/add

The fact that you have "http" instead of "https" is therefore irrelevant, as the value stored is only the relative part of the URL. So whatever your environment (dev, preprod, prod) your redirection will always work.